# Screen Savers not working after Maverick Upgrade

Tags: 10.10, upgrade, screensaver

After doing an in-place upgrade from Lucid to Maverick, my screen savers no longer work. I get a background that the panel/title-bar image, but no screen saver. I see no messages in dmesg, and don't really know where to start looking for causes for this problem.

Comment: Let me preface this by saying that I don't really know what this could be. With that said you could maybe try reinstalling gnome-screensaver. I can't guarantee that will actually do anything though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed today after changing my screensaver to something else that the "skyrocket" screensaver process was still running, even though a different screensaver had been selected. After manually killing the process things seem to return to normal. I'm unsure at this point if there's a problem with the "SkyRocket" screensaver specifically, or something else.